# Nested output from mongo aggregate query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is right out of the mongo aggregation documentation. Lets say I have these set of documents:

```
{ _id: 1, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2012-11-02T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 50 }
{ _id: 2, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-01T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 100 }
{ _id: 3, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 25 }
{ _id: 4, cust_id: "xyz1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-10-11T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "D", amount: 125 }
{ _id: 5, cust_id: "abc1", ord_date: ISODate("2013-11-12T17:04:11.102Z"), status: "A", amount: 25 }
```

I can run this aggregate query:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
                 { $match: { status: "A" } },
                 { $group: { _id: "$cust_id", total: { $sum: "$amount" } } },
                 { $sort: { total: -1 } }
               ])
```

To get this response:

```
{ "_id" : "xyz1", "total" : 100 }
{ "_id" : "abc1", "total" : 75 }
```

But what if a want the response in a nested format? Any way of achieving that without using mapReduce? Something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "xyz1", "amount": { "total" : 100 } }
{ "_id" : "abc1", "amount": { "total" : 75 } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to project your documents using the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$cust_id", 
        "total": { "$sum": "$amount" }
    }}, 
    { "$project": { "amount.total": "$total" } },
    { "$sort": { "amount.total": -1 } }

])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "_id" : "xyz1", "amount" : { "total" : 250 } }
{ "_id" : "abc1", "amount" : { "total" : 75 } }
```